# How to use hex color value in python reportlab pdf generation

Tags: python, reportlab

I am trying to generate multi page pdf document reading some `py` files and other doc files. I am trying do it with `SimpleDocTemplate` instead of `Canvas`. Now I am trying to color the text with hex value. I tried following:

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate
from reportlab.platypus.para import Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet

doc_content = []
styles=getSampleStyleSheet()

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("form_letter.pdf",pagesize=letter,
                        rightMargin=72,leftMargin=72,
                        topMargin=72,bottomMargin=18)

titleFormat = '<font size="16" name="Helvetica" color="#FF8100"><b><i>%s</i></b></font>'

def generateDoc(docName):
    paraTitle = Paragraph(titleFormat % 'Title', styles["Normal"])
    doc_content.append(paraTitle)
    doc.build(doc_content)

generateDoc("temp.pdf")
```

But this gives me error

```
AttributeError: module 'reportlab.lib.colors' has no attribute '#FF8100'
```

I also tried `0xFF8100`, but it was giving same error:

```
AttributeError: module 'reportlab.lib.colors' has no attribute '0xFF8100'
```

When I use some named color say `red`, it works fine. How can use hex color values?

Answer (score 4):

It's always better to create your custom StyleSheet if you need different colors of text in the pdf.
You can pass your hex code value to `def HexColor(val, htmlOnly=False, hasAlpha=False):`

```
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate
from reportlab.platypus.para import Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle

doc_content = []
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()

#creating custom stylesheet
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Content',
                          fontFamily='Helvetica',
                          fontSize=8,
                          textColor=colors.HexColor("#FF8100")))

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("form_letter.pdf", pagesize=letter,
                        rightMargin=72, leftMargin=72,
                        topMargin=72, bottomMargin=18)

#using a sample text here
titleFormat = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."


def generateDoc(docName):
    paraTitle = Paragraph(titleFormat, styles["Content"])
    doc_content.append(paraTitle)
    doc.build(doc_content)


generateDoc("temp.pdf")
```

Comment: I have some more doubts. I was able to generate the desired doc in desired format with [`pyfpdf`](https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf). The only issue was that I was not able to add bookmarks to that pdf. So I started to look at other libraries, now reportlab but started facing new issues. The color was one such issue but it seems that it will work if I follow your answer. The another issue is that I am not able to apply code font (like Courier New or Consolas) to code snippets I am adding to pdf. I tired adding true type font explicitly with `pdfmetrics.registerFont()`. But it is not working.

Comment: [...continued] (didnt tried bookmarks yet) Are you sure we can do bookmarks, code font in reportlab? Or can I read doc prepared with pyfpdf using reportlab and then add bookmarks to it (using reportlab)?

Comment: I had never tried bookmarks in reportlab bit I think it should be doable.

Comment: read this blog  http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/07/19/reportlab-all-about-fonts/

Comment: Yeah I tried that. The blog says "...Occasionally this doesn’t work for some reason. Perhaps the ttf file is poorly defined or corrupt. I don’t really know..."